Sed to extract substring surrounded by strings
I am trying to use sed to extract a substring from a string, where the substring is surrounded by other strings.
Here's an example string:
Test: 1000 calls, 15307 milliseconds, 11 minimum, 37 maximum, 15 average, top five [37,35,34,32,31]

and I want to extract the "average" value (in the example above, that would be 15.
I have tried:
echo "Test: 1000 calls, 15307 milliseconds, 11 minimum, 37 maximum, 15 average, top five [37,35,34,32,31]" | sed 's/.*\(maximum,.*\)average/\1/'

but the output I am getting is:
maximum, 15 , top five [37,35,34,32,31]

How can I NOT include the "maximum, " that is in front of the "15", and NOT include the part of the string that is after the "15"?
EDIT: Apologies I messed up and used wrong example - I will correct it in a bit :( !
EDIT 2: I have correct the example.

sed is not the best tool to extract substrings, but in this case, it can be used:
echo "Test: 1000 calls, 15307 milliseconds, 11 minimum, 37 maximum, 15 average, top five [37,35,34,32,31]" \
| sed 's/.* \([0-9]*\) average,.*/\1/'

I.e. match everything up to a number before average, remember the number, and replace everything with the number.

choroba - That works!  Can you change you comment to an answer and then I will accept it?

You can also do it with grep:
echo 'Test: 1000 calls, 15307 milliseconds, 11 minimum, 37 maximum, 15 average, top five [37,35,34,32,31]' \
| grep -P -o 'maximum,\s+\K\S+'

or with Perl:
echo 'Test: 1000 calls, 15307 milliseconds, 11 minimum, 37 maximum, 15 average, top five [37,35,34,32,31]' \
| perl -lne 'print $1 if /(\S+)\s+average/'

Output:
15

Here, GNU grep uses the following options:
-P : Use Perl regexes.
-o : Print the matches only (1 match per line), not the entire lines.
\K : Cause the regex engine to "keep" everything it had matched prior to the \K and not include it in the match. Specifically, ignore the preceding part of the regex when printing the match.
\s+ : 1 or more whitespace characters.
\S+ : 1 or more non-whitespace characters.
The Perl one-liner uses these command line flags:
-e : Tells Perl to look for code in-line, instead of in a file.
-n : Loop over the input one line at a time, assigning it to $_ by default.
-l : Strip the input line separator ("\n" on *NIX by default) before executing the code in-line, and append it when printing.
(\S+) : Capture 1 or more non-whitespace characters using parentheses into variable $1.
See also:

perldoc perlrun: how to execute the Perl interpreter: command line switches
perlre - Perl regular expressions

